# Segmentation in 8086

Tags: x86-16, memory-segmentation

We define segments for example like this.

```
data segment
msg db "hello$"
data ends

extra segment
numbers db 10,13,15
extra ends

code segment 
... my codes.
code ends
```

Compiler automatically assigns segment addresses to the above program. Generally within same 64K block. I want data segment address to be C000:0000 , Extra segment address is B000:0000 with containing values (Hello, numbers ). In my code section, i want to get that values from memory. is it probable that compiler locates these values to the memory locations before code segment starts ?

Comment: No, an EXE can have separate code and data segments that the program-loader put in different places.  I'm pretty sure a `.com` executable can only be 64k total, because it uses a "tiny" memory model (everything in the same segment)

Comment: [edit] your question with that extra detail so you can make it more readable than in a comment, and so future readers will see it.  Are you making a `.exe` or a `.com`, or developing your own custom OS, or what?

Comment: Sorry @PeterCordes , this is my first message and thanks.

Comment: On a PC it is not possible for the compiler to locate your segments at those locations; or at least, it can't actually be loaded with those addresses, because a PC only has RAM in the low 640K of the address space (segments 0000-9FFF).  Video memory is mapped in the B000 segment, and ROM in C000-FFFF.  Are you designing this for some embedded system with a different memory map?

Comment: If you want to load segments at specific addresses, you generally use the `org` directive -- eg `org 0xc0000` right after `data segment` and `org 0xb0000` right after `extra segment` for the addresses you specified...

Comment: B000, C000 was an example. I use mov ax,7000h, mov ds,ax  and assume ds:data to access 7000:0000 segment but it is empty, doesn't contain "Hello$" string. It is normal because RAM didn't store anything yet. I can write that location. I wonder that, does compiler automatically locate "Hello$" string to that location as an initialization before code segment starts ?